# scipy integration with an array as limits

Tags: python-3.x, scipy, numerical-integration

Just facing a problem from integration in python, let say if I have f(x) = x as my integrand and we all know that after the integration of f(x) the outcome will be (x**2)/2.

But if I set the lower limit be 0, and the upper limit as an array, let say 1,2,3

I want an array of [1/2, 2, 9/2] as my outcome.

How do we do this in python? seems like it won't take an array as the upper limit.

Thanks!

Comment: We could ask for actual code, but I think the solution is obvious - **iterate**

Comment: thanks, but I am quite new to python, can you share what you have in mind?